# mysql sort by a few groups

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

How to sort mysql query first by

```
(`superVip` DESC, `editDate` DESC) then (`vip` DESC, `editDate` DESC) (other ads sort by ID)
```

something like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM `ads` 
ORDER BY (`superVip` DESC, `editDate` DESC), (`vip` DESC, `editDate` DESC), `id` DESC
```

Comment: Please show current result and expected result

Answer (score 0):

Just a matter of sintax, look:

```
SELECT * FROM ads ORDER BY superVip DESC, editDate DESC, vip DESC, editDate DESC, id DESC
```